# How to solve exception thrown in traversing forest

Tags: c, exception, tree, runtime-error

Question: Compute numbers of leaves in forest. Promblem: After debugging and printing a part of data, when I traverse `printf("%d ", node->data);`, incurred in a runtime error, that is, exception thrown: read access violation.

MainFunc.c

```
#include "AllFun.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CsNode* tree = (CsNode*)malloc(sizeof(CsNode));
    if (tree) {
        tree->firstchild = NULL;
        tree->nextsibling = NULL;
        CreateTree(&tree);
        preOrder(tree);
        int leaves = CountForestLeaves(tree);
        printf("leaves: %d", leaves);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

AllFun.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct CsNode {
    struct CsNode* firstchild;
    struct CsNode* nextsibling;
    int data;
}CsNode;
void CreateTree(CsNode** node);
void preOrder(CsNode* node);
int CountForestLeaves(CsNode* tree);
```

OtheFunc.c

```
#include "AllFun.h"
void CreateTree(CsNode** node)
{
    int data;
    printf("please input data: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &data);
    if (data != -1) {
        *node = (CsNode*)malloc(sizeof(CsNode));
                (*node)->data = data;
                (*node)->firstchild = NULL;
                (*node)->nextsibling = NULL;
        CreateTree(&(*node)->firstchild);
        CreateTree(&(*node)->nextsibling);
    }
}
void preOrder(CsNode* node)
{
    if (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        preOrder(node->firstchild);
        preOrder(node->nextsibling);
    }
}
int CountForestLeaves(CsNode* tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (tree->firstchild == NULL)
        return 1 + CountForestLeaves(tree->nextsibling);
    else {
        return CountForestLeaves(tree->firstchild) + CountForestLeaves(tree->nextsibling);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you assure that `firstchild` and `nextsibling` are set to `NULL`?

Comment: The alias name and struct name are same 'CsNode' in AllFun.h, does changing that helps?

Comment: Shouldn't set to `NULL` as initialization?`@Cheatah`

Comment: Cheatah's question was "where do you", not "should it". Yes, you should, but do you?

Comment: malloc doesn't zero-out the chunk of memory, unlike calloc. And it is fairly safe to treat "all zeroes" as null pointers. But it's always better to be explicit and initialize every member of the struct.

Comment: Debugging successfully! Corrected.